# Mi código se ejecuta varias veces al usar Ajax.Beginform - MVC 5

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

Estoy implementando un formulario CRUD en mi proyecto ASP.net MVC 5 utilizando Html.Beginform el donde se ejecutaba sin problemas, ahora que estoy haciendo el cambio de pasar a usar Ajax.Beginform el mismo código que está en el controlador para hacer CRUD se ejecuta 2 veces (en el caso de insertar duplica datos) cuando hago paso a paso veo que se termina de ejecutar lo del controlador y nuevamente comienza a repetir de 2 a 4 veces de forma aleatoria.

También reviso los procesos por SQL profiler y mis consultas se repiten.

Mi pregunta es si el uso de Ajax.Beginform cause este cambio pues los métodos de controlados es el mismo al que usaba con Html y no tenía este inconveniente...

Gracias por su ayuda.

Esto es lo único que he cambiado uso de llamado de Html a Ajax.

**- Html.Beginform**

```
{
@using (Html.BeginForm("CRequerimiento", "Requerimiento", new { message01 = ViewBag.ResultadoOK, message02 = ViewBag.ResultadoKO }, FormMethod.Post, new { role = "form" }))
}
```

**- Ajax.Beginform**

```
{
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("CRequerimiento", "Requerimiento", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "divDatos" }))
}
```

También agregué las key's e instale el Unobtrusive en mi proyecto.

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ejemplo de unos una acción de mi controlador:

```
    public ActionResult CargarRequerimiento_Datos (string tiDocu, string NuReqi)
    {
        // 1. Obtenemos repo_Requerimiento y el modelo RequerimientoModelo
        Repositorio.Almacen.repo_Requerimiento Buscar_Datos = new Repositorio.Almacen.repo_Requerimiento();
        RequerimientoModelo m = new RequerimientoModelo();

        // 2. Asignamos valores a utilizar para la búsqueda del documento
        m.CodEmpr = VariableGlobal.scodEmpresa;
        m.TipoDocu = tiDocu;
        m.NuDocu = NuReqi;

        // 3. Ejecutamos método que busca y obtiene resultado
        Buscar_Datos.CargadRQ(m);

        // 4. Asignamos datos obenidos en la vista de Datos y Detalles
        ViewBag.ActivaVentana = "tab_1";
        ViewBag.EstadoDetalle = true;
        ViewBag.BuscarReq = true;
        ViewBag.Message01 = VariableGlobal.sNombreUsuario;
        ViewBag.Message02 = VariableGlobal.sGrupoUsuario;

        m.fecha_Inicial = DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        m.fecha_Final = DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

        return View("Requerimiento", m);

    }
```

En este y en todas las acciones que realizo se ejecuta varias veces.

El siguiente código es mi PartiView (tengo varias similares) este partial va al controlador y me devuelve un grid listado.

```
{
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("BRequerimiento", "Requerimiento", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "divBusqueda" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    if (ViewBag.ActivaVentana == "tab_3")
    {
        <div class="alert-success" style="margin-left:35px; margin-right:55px; margin-bottom:10px;">@ViewBag.ResultadoOK</div>
        <div class="alert-danger" style="margin-left:35px; margin-right:55px; margin-bottom:10px;">@ViewBag.ResultadoKO</div>
    }
    <div class="form-group">
        <p>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.TipoDocu, "Tipo Documento", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label", @readonly = true })
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TipoDocu, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control1 text-center", style = "margin-left: 0px;", @Value = Model.TipoDocu, @readonly = true })
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.NomDocu, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-md-pull-6 control-label text-center", style = "width: 229px;", @disabled = "disabled", @Value = Model.NomDocu })
            <button type="submit" value="Buscar" name="submitButton" class="btn btn-info">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Buscar
            </button>
        </p>
        <p>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.fecha_Inicial, "Fecha Inicial", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.fecha_Inicial, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-md-pull-4 control-label", @type = "date", @value = Model.fecha_Inicial })
        </p>
        <p>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.fecha_Final, "Fecha Final", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.fecha_Final, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-md-pull-4 control-label", @type = "date", @value = Model.fecha_Final })
        </p>
    </div>
}

<hr />
<div class="form-group-sm">
    <label class="col-md-2" style="width: 110px; padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px; margin-left: 30px;">Anulado</label>
    <input type="text" class="col-md-1" style="background:#f9acac; padding-left: 0px;padding-right: 0px;width: 44px;margin-right: 30px;" readonly />
    <label class="col-md-2" style="width: 110px; padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px;">Validado</label>
    <input type="text" class="col-md-1" style="background:#A28DAD; padding-left: 0px;padding-right: 0px;width: 44px;margin-right: 30px;" readonly />
    <label class="col-md-2" style="width: 110px; padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px;">Aprobado</label>
    <input type="text" class="col-md-1" style="background:#b6f9d2; padding-left: 0px;padding-right: 0px;width: 44px;margin-right: 30px;" readonly />
    <label class="col-md-2" style="width: 110px; padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px;">Rechazado</label>
    <input type="text" class="col-md-1" style="background:#FFD9A5; padding-left: 0px;padding-right: 0px;width: 44px;margin-right: 30px;" readonly />
</div>
<br />
<hr />

<div id="divBusqueda" class="container">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function Mostrar_Requerimiento(TIPO, NRO_REQUERIMIENTO)
    {
        //alert(NRO_REQUERIMIENTO);
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("CargarRequerimiento_Datos", "Requerimiento")',
            method: "POST",
            data: { 'tiDocu': TIPO, 'NuReqi': NRO_REQUERIMIENTO },
            success: function (response) {
                //document.write(response);
                $('#divPage').html(response);

            },

            error: function (errormessage) {
                alert(errormessage.responseText);
            },

            async: true
        });
    }
</script>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
}
```

El jquery.unobtrusive lo he colocado de distintas formas en el layout y lo utilizo con @section scripts en cada vista parcial y en este caso lo he colocado los scripts al fina de mis vistas parciales.... Pero en ambos se ejecuta 2 veces el llamado a la acción del controlador.

**BOTONES QUE UTILIZO PARA CADA LLAMAR A CADA ACCIÓN**

```
{
<div class="container" style="width:700px; border-radius:10px; margin-bottom:5px; margin-top:5px; margin-left:1px;">

        <div class="form-botones">

            <button type="submit" value="Nuevo" name="submitButton" class="btn btn-default">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-new-window"></span> Nuevo
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="form-botones">

            <button type="submit" value="Guardar" name="submitButton" class="btn btn-success">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></span> Guardar
            </button>
        </div>

        <div class="form-botones">

            <button type="submit" value="Modificar" name="submitButton" class="btn btn-warning">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Modificar
            </button>
        </div>

        <div class="form-botones">

            <button type="submit" value="Eliminar" name="submitButton" class="btn btn-danger">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-scissors"></span> Eliminar
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="form-botones">

            <button type="submit" value="Buscar" name="submitButton" class="btn btn-info">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Buscar
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Cabe la posibilidad que se trate de un malfuncionamiento del mouse, utiliza el teclado y dale enter seleccionando mediante TAB. Edita la pregunta y agrega los detalles del controlador y de la vista, será más fácil para ti que la comunidad pueda reproducir el escenario :D

Comment: En realidad sucede con todas las acciones que llamo utilizando Ajax.BeginForm acabo de hacer una prueba de grabar con el teclado y me realizó el registró de 2 items....

Comment: Edita la pregunta nuevamente y agrega las ubicaciones donde tienes `jquery.unobtrusive`

Comment: Listo ya lo añadí, actualmente se encuentra al final de cada vista parcial, también he intentado ubicarlo en el layout para luego llamarlo por @section scripts de mi vista parcial pero igual se ejecuta varias veces el código de la acción de mi controlador.

Comment: Revisa la respuesta :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu problema está aquí:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
```

¿Por qué usar ambas versiones? Suficiente con 1: si estás en desarrollo ve por la versión full y si estás en producción ve por la versión minificada.

**Utiliza  1 sola llamada al dicho archivo.**

Sucede que al existir más de 1 archivo `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js`, se va a ejecutar más de 1 vez.

Si la curiosidad te lleva a revisar lo que hay en dichos archivos, encuentras:

```
$(document).on("click", "form[data-ajax=true] ...
```

Esto quiere decir que se va a ejecutar un submit en cada formulario que tenga el data-attribute `data-ajax=true` y si este archivo está repetido N veces, se va a ejecutar N veces.

Comment: Realicé el cambio tal como me aconsejas (~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js) y lo coloqué en el layout (es el único lugar donde llama al jquery) y vuelvo a hacer operaciones CRUD y se duplica de 2 a mas veces de forma aleatoria. :/

Comment: Configurado aquí: bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/unobtrusive").Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")); *******     @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/unobtrusive")

Comment: Revisa que sólo exista una llamada a dicho archivo

Comment: @RobinsonAscencioPeña ¿hubo alguna llamada adicional?

Comment: Lo indicado por el colega como respuesta me ayudó, adicional añadí el script en el bundles para posteriormente limpiar el proyecto y volver a ejecutarlo y ahora si me funciona sin repetir las consultar. Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: ¡Perfecto¡ con cariño hermano, que tengas un excelente día, sigue desarrollando con todo el power 2.0! Éxitos con el proyecto :D